# Figsize in pixels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to make two side by side graphs take up half my screen (resolution of 1600). Matplotlib defines figure size in inches and dots per inch. How can I use these to make each 810 pixels and is there any difference between the two?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4), dpi=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2), dpi=200)
```

Comment: figsize is in inches and dpi is pixels per inch.  The obvious multiplication does not work?

Comment: I didn't know that figsize is inches. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The product of your figure size and the resolution of the figure in dots-per-inch needs to match the desired width and height of the image. At a screen resolution of e.g. 1600 × 900 pixels an image should be 800 pixels wide to take up half your screen, so this looks good:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4), dpi=100)
```

“The native figure size unit in Matplotlib is inches, deriving from print industry standards.” You can, however, specify your figures in other units like centimeters or pixels, see [Matplotlib documentation: Figure size in different units](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_size_units.html), so this should also work for you:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(800*px, 400*px))
```